# Best practice for checking for undefined php variables?

Tags: php, variables, undefined

On a menu page, I have a

```
class='$ActiveAbout'
```

On a separate page I defined

```
$ActiveAbout = 'active'
```

I also have `$ActiveSite`, `$ActiveHome`, `$ActiveAdd`, etc so only one of those is used at a time.  Doing this will cause the Notice: Undefined variable: ActiveSite message.

So far, I can see two solutions

```
$ActiveSite = $ActiveSite ?? '';

if(!isset($ActiveSite)) {$ActiveSite = '';}
```

Are those my best choices?  Is that a better way to see if it isn't set?

Currently using PHP 5.6 but going to PHP 7.

Additional info:

It was a lot easier to have:

```php
<li class='$AboutHome'><a href='home.php'>
<li class='$AboutAbout'><a href='about.php'>
<li class='$AboutContact'><a href='contact.php'>
```

Then on the home.php, I would have: $AboutHome='active'  then on the menu page, it would fill in that variable while the other 2 are just empty because they aren't set, thus they don't get the 'active' style.

Comment: Just initialize all the variables at the beginning, and later assign the one that needs to be active.

Comment: Why not just use a single variable `$active`, which you set to `about`, `site`, etc.?

Comment: It was a lot easier to have:

<li class='$AboutHome'><a href='home.php'>
<li class='$AboutAbout'><a href='about.php'>
<li class='$AboutContact'><a href='contact.php'>

Then on the home.php, I would have: $AboutHome='active'  then on the menu page, it would fill in that variable while the other 2 are just empty because they aren't set, thus they don't get the 'active' style.

Comment: Actually a _lot_ easier would be if you actually kept your menu data in some sort of array, so that you can generate the code for the menu in a loop. Then you only have to check whether the current item refers to the current page in one single place as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use a single variable `$active`, which you test later.

```
$active = 'about';
...
<div id='about' <?php if ($active == 'about') echo "class='active'"; ?>>
```

Or if you want to be able to do multiple classes, and just `active` is optional:

```
<div id='about' class='<?php if ($active == 'about') echo "active"; ?>'>
```

Comment: I would make a small change in code: `<div id="about" class="<?php if ($active == 'about') echo 'active'; ?>" >`, in this case we just stick with class and not with all possible classes which may be applied to this block.